# Glassfish deploy command with createtables error

Tags: jdbc, deployment, glassfish

I have an application packaged as .war file. I want to deploy this web application to Glassfish v4.0 server using this command:

```
./asadmin deploy --force=true --createtables --contextroot test /tmp/test.war
```

Deployment without --createtables parameter works fine, however I want the tables to be generated/updated during the deployment. On my local server where I have only one JDBC resource defined in glassfish it works fine. But on the test server there are more JDBC resources defined with limited privilegies and one JDBC resource that I want to use just for this task. How do I tell glassfish to use this particular JDBC resource when creating and updating tables?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide {true|false} to the --createtables option:

```
./asadmin deploy --force=true --createtables=true --contextroot test /tmp/test.war
```